# Are there any snacks that use a large amount of black sesame seeds?

Tags: dessert, snacks

A dietician I was working with recommended eating 3 tbsp a day of black sesame seeds. If I can't do that, I'd at least like to do 1-2. Are there any snacks that uses a lot of black sesame seeds that I could eat easily (as opposed to sprinkling them over a dish or a salad, for example)? Only restriction is I don't eat seafood (so sushi is out).

Most of the recipes I've found online use it as a garnish, or are in something like ice cream / pudding -- which I would imagine are not the best things to eat every day.

Comment: You can roll them into a thin dough and bake them as crisps. Sesame butter made from toasted seeds is also great. 3 tablespoonfuls are not such a huge quantity. Sesame coated baked or fried chicken is yet another possibility.

Comment: Hey, this kind of question is pretty broad and opinion based, not a great fit for this site, since there isn't really a way to rank the answers and it encourages lists of equally-plausible possibilities - you might want to narrow down what would make one answer a better fit than another and edit in how you would judge them to try to avoid this.  [also, I thought of sesame hard candy - basically sesame brittle, lots of sesame added to a little bit of sugar candy binder.  Might not be healthy to eat a whole batch in a day, but a reasonably sized piece should be fine.]

Comment: @Megha How would you recommend I improve it? I can't think of a way to make it more specific, other than asking for a recipe that takes less time and gets the required serving in. The one that would be the best would be a min-max, I'd imagine -- but I don't know if I should include that? I already said it should be a snack, and not a dessert, too.

Comment: @Marco - well, having more restrictions or guidelines for what you *do* want helps - ie, stored at room temp, or savory, or cooked, or portable, or sturdy enough to grab and go, or low volume.  As it is, the ideal answer is just measure out the sesame and munch away, that takes no preparation or extra ingredients - so I suspect you're actually looking for snacks that are delicious, or nutritious, or interesting and that's too subjective for a Q&A.  As-is, it might not be suitable for the site, it is idea generation - though you can ask for that in chat when you get a little more reputation.

Comment: You might have better luck with a question about possible binders to hold the snack together, and what preparation would be needed to get the binders to hold on to the sesame - since min-maxing would really be mostly the seeds with a bit of binder.

Comment: If you have a reasonably well stocked asian grocery store, there should be snacks made from black sesame seeds. For example, you can often find sesame snaps made from black sesame seeds.

Comment: Don't rule out sushi entirely; you can make excellent vegetable based sushi.

Answer (score 1):

You can make black sesame seed soup. It's mildly sweet and is often eaten at breakfast by Chinese. Black sesame seeds are unhulled unlike most (white) sesame seeds sold in North America and Europe which are hulled. So if you eat the seeds whole, you'll get little benefit from them as they basically pass through your digestive tract unchanged. The soup uses ground seeds.

I know we're not supposed to give out requests for recipes but you're not asking so I hope I'm not wrong in giving you a link to the soup recipe. I have no idea if there are other sites with a recipe for it. http://www.chinasichuanfood.com/black-sesame-pastesoup/

A suggestion in toasting black sesame seeds. It's easy to toast white sesame seeds in a pan on the stove and tell by the colour change to a light golden brown when they're done. Black ones aren't so easy to tell by looks though. I found that adding some of the pale coloured seeds with the black ones is a good way to know. When the pale seeds start showing a light golden colour, you'll know the black are also toasted enough. Be careful not to over-toast them or they'll taste unpleasantly bitter.

There are other ways of using black sesame seeds but this is the easiest.